# TFS Build - MSBuild 14 x64 memory leak or too high memory consumption

Tags: tfs, msbuild

Recently we've upgraded our solution (with hundreds of projects) to target .NET 4.6.1. We've also changed the ToolsVersion to 14.0. Locally on dev machines everything works fine, but once we changed in the TFS templates to use the new msbuild (14.0) the memory usage during the actual build went sky high - over 8 GB's of memory used by the msbuild process.

Did anyone else had such a problem? Any ideas what can cause it to go that high?

P.S. We have no project references, only assembly references. Each project as a post-build event does copy assembly dll into specific common folder and then it does GAC it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a known bug which was fixed in the master branch of the MSBuild on the github.

https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/commit/f8f33a9da283b300a14a1540414d0358b01bfa46